# QTError : Library not loaded: @rpath/libQt5PrintSupport.5.dylib

Tags: qt

I am trying to deploy the default `QT Widget` app and am getting the following error :

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDMGProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Release/QTDMGProj.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDMGProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Release/QTDMGProj.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib"
Found metadata in lib /Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDMGProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Release/QTDMGProj.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "cocoa"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QCocoaIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329218
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("cocoa")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDMGProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Release/QTDMGProj.app/Contents/MacOS/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDMGProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Release/QTDMGProj.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib: (dlopen(/Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDMGProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Release/QTDMGProj.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib, 133): Library not loaded: @rpath/libQt5PrintSupport.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDMGProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Release/QTDMGProj.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib
  Reason: image not found)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDMGProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Release/QTDMGProj.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib" : "Cannot load library /Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDMGProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Release/QTDMGProj.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib: (dlopen(/Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDMGProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Release/QTDMGProj.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib, 133): Library not loaded: @rpath/libQt5PrintSupport.5.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Users/arqam/Desktop/Junk/build-QTDMGProj-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_clang_64bit-Release/QTDMGProj.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib\n  Reason: image not found)"
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: cocoa.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Abort trap: 6
```

This is happening on the default QT Widget application.

My project sample github link : https://github.com/torrtuga/QTDMGDebug

So is there anything that I am missing in my QT environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you use otool on your program like so:

```
otool -L myProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/myProgram
```

You may see that print support dylib listed in the output as a dependency. It looks like this basically:

```
./NetAnim:
    @rpath/libQt5PrintSupport.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.9.0, current version 5.9.7)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    @rpath/libQt5Widgets.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.9.0, current version 5.9.7)
    @rpath/libQt5Gui.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.9.0, current version 5.9.7)
    @rpath/libQt5Core.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.9.0, current version 5.9.7)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.100.5)
```

If you're not familiar with otool, basically it's a macOS command line tool you can pass your program binary to, and it will spit out what your dependencies are. Usually these are .dylib files (dylib -> dynamic library -> dynamic library just means loaded at runtime basically, so it's a file you need when you run your program)

Ok so in that output above, there is that term rpath all over the place. That just means runtime search path. So basically it points to a folder where your program is going to search for it's dependencies. You can add as many rpaths as you want using install_name_tool like so:

```
install_name_tool -add_rpath /path/to/folder myProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/myProgram
```

So what I recommend is to find libQt5PrintSupport.5.dylib somewhere, probably in your QT folder, and then copy it into an rpath folder.

You can see all your rpath folders by going:

```
otool -l ./myProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/myProgram
```

and looking for LC_RPATH near the end of your output.

Mine looks like this:

```
cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 32
         path @executable_path (offset 12)
```

I set my path to @executable_path. That's the path to myProgram.app/Contents/MacOS/myProgram, basically the program itself.

@loader_path is the path to a file that loads a dylib file. A dylib file can load other dylib files as dependencies so @loader_path/ can be useful as like a relative path kind of tool.

@rpath is usually pointing to `@executable_path/../Frameworks` or usually some system location like `/usr/local/lib` or maybe even something like `usr/local/anaconda3/bin` or something like that (if you had anaconda as like a dependency for example)
Usually there is always a Frameworks folder in every app bundle that has a bunch of dylibs and dependencies in it. Often you can throw the missing dylib in there as long as the rpath is pointing to it.

Also, I noticed I couldn't find an instance of that printsupport dylib anywhere in my QT5 folder, but,
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/fullsdk-darwin/tools/+/bc0f8b4ee07b1d823eb508f4aebc1a06a06fe6b6/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.5.5.dylib
This seems to indicate that maybe you can just download the Android package using your MaintenenceTool.app in your QT folder and get the dylib that way.

Probably you can search QT source on Github for that dylib or something and figure out what version you need. Qt is open source after all, with the exception of some enterprise features.